# Add dimensions under product title product overview Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For the website that i'am building i try to get the dimensions of the product directly under the product title on the overview.

[Here i want the dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7043Q.png)

in ACF i made a field called 'productkaart_afmetingen' were i can fill in the dimensions data at every product. But i can't manage to load it in under the product title.

i tried adding

```
the_field('productkaart_afmetingen');
```

to the content-product.php in my child theme folder but this made the dimensions appear above the title and i can't manage to get is under the title

Answer (score 0):

Code goes in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'display_acf_field_under_images', 30 );
  
function display_acf_field_under_images() {
  echo '<b>ACF Field:</b> ' . get_field('productkaart_afmetingen');
  // Note: 'productkaart_afmetingen' is the slug of the ACF

}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately this code does not display the dimensions ad all. When i change the code to:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_acf_field_under_images', 30 );
  
function display_acf_field_under_images() {
  echo '<b>ACF Field:</b> ' . get_field('productkaart_afmetingen');
  // Note: 'productkaart_afmetingen' is the slug of the ACF

}`

It now shows up but in between the product picture & title. But i can't manage to make it show up in between the 'Title' & the 'Price'

Comment: Check out the hooks for the Single Product Page: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ you can hook where you need it.